# Is it advisable to run Apache in a chroot jail?

Tags: apache-2.2, chroot

I have been advised by a sysadmin guy I know, to run Apache in a chroot jail, for increased security.

I have the following questions:

1. Is this advisable (i.e. are there any 'gotcha's that I need to be aware of) ?
2. Does running Apache in a chroot jail affect its ability issues like performance and scalability?

He also advised that I run my databases (mySQL and PostgreSQL), in separate chroot jails.

Is this something that is often done in production systems

**[Edit]**

Forgot to say, Server is running on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS

Comment: You mention jails: are you on one of the *BSD's? If not, and you're on Linux, SELinux in enforcing mode will probably take care of all your security problems quite well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrooting is a good security measure, it limits the possibilities to compromise the system in case of a successfull exploit but there are also ways in some case to evade from a chroot, so it is not a definitive way to protect the system.

I'm not aware of any disavantage regarding performance and scalability. Concerning database access, it is generaly done with a link to the socket inside the chroot this way you don't have to open any networking port for database connectivity.

EDIT: below is a sample for mysql access taken from an OpenBSD rc.local (OpenBSD chrooted httpd)

```
if [ X"${mysql_server_flags-NO}" != X"NO" -a -x /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe ]; then
        rm -R /var/www/var/run/mysql
        mkdir -p /var/www/var/run/mysql
        chown _mysql:_mysql   /var/www/var/run/mysql
        echo -n 'MySQL server: '; /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe --user=_mysql ${mysql_server_flags} &
        sleep 10
        ln -f /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock /var/www/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
fi
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for good, straight answer. could you please elaborate some more (i.e. explain) what you mean by 'link to the socket inside the chroot'. can you provide an example?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I heartily second the notion of running all DMZ apps in chroot jails.  However, the DB backend is typically not in the DMZ, but on an internal network.

Answer (score -2):

I have two programs, one of them is apache httpd, communicating each other via unix domain socket. I have switched them to run under chroot, and then %10 performance loss. It depends on the running applications I think. I did not hear any performance loss for Apache under chroot before, so It looks like my second app is lost performance under chroot.